# About cryptocurrency on memory pool, Web wallet and Confirmations (LItecoin)

Tags: c++, bitcoin, cryptocurrency, litecoin

> Note : If you don't known the bitcoin/Litecoin Source program, Then This Question is not for you. Please try not to Downgrade

I have created a alternative coin by using the fork of litecoin, and succeeded, But stil there exist some doubts about it. I googled for solution but can't able to find. If someone know the Answers or link please suggest

**1. How can i reduce the Default Confirmation '101' for the coins to mature ? Instead that i need only 50 Confirmation.**

**2. Does the memory pool only works for the raw transaction between to address ? why not for mining transactions and whats its use ?**

**3. Is the Web wallets like LiteVault, Blockchain.info  are working with the property of wallet accounts ? instead of creating each Wallet.dat file ?**

Am working on the Litecoin v0.15 
and the main class file in **chainparam.cpp**

```
    class CMainParams : public CChainParams {
public:
    CMainParams() {
        strNetworkID = "main";
        consensus.nSubsidyHalvingInterval = 840000;
        consensus.BIP34Height = 710000;
        consensus.BIP34Hash = uint256S("fa09d204a83a768ed5a7c8d441fa62f2043abf420cff1226c7b4329aeb9d51cf");
        consensus.BIP65Height = 918684; // bab3041e8977e0dc3eeff63fe707b92bde1dd449d8efafb248c27c8264cc311a
        consensus.BIP66Height = 811879; // 7aceee012833fa8952f8835d8b1b3ae233cd6ab08fdb27a771d2bd7bdc491894
        consensus.powLimit = uint256S("00000fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"); 
        consensus.nPowTargetTimespan = 3.5 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 3.5 days
        consensus.nPowTargetSpacing = 2.5 * 60;
        consensus.fPowAllowMinDifficultyBlocks = false;
        consensus.fPowNoRetargeting = false;
        consensus.nRuleChangeActivationThreshold = 6048; // 75% of 8064
        consensus.nMinerConfirmationWindow = 8064; // nPowTargetTimespan / nPowTargetSpacing * 4
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].bit = 28;
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].nStartTime = 1199145601; // January 1, 2008
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].nTimeout = 1230767999; // December 31, 2008

        // Deployment of BIP68, BIP112, and BIP113.
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].bit = 0;
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].nStartTime = 1485561600; // January 28, 2017
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].nTimeout = 1517356801; // January 31st, 2018

        // Deployment of SegWit (BIP141, BIP143, and BIP147)
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].bit = 1;
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].nStartTime = 1485561600; // January 28, 2017
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].nTimeout = 1517356801; // January 31st, 2018

        // The best chain should have at least this much work.
        consensus.nMinimumChainWork = uint256S("0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002ebcfe2dd9eff82666");

        // By default assume that the signatures in ancestors of this block are valid.
        consensus.defaultAssumeValid = uint256S("0x59c9b9d3fec105bdc716d84caa7579503d5b05b73618d0bf2d5fa639f780a011"); //1353397

        pchMessageStart[0] = 0xfb;
        pchMessageStart[1] = 0xc0;
        pchMessageStart[2] = 0xb6;
        pchMessageStart[3] = 0xdb;
        nDefaultPort = 9333;
        nPruneAfterHeight = 100000;

        genesis = CreateGenesisBlock(1317972665, 2084524493, 0x1e0ffff0, 1, 50 * COIN);
        consensus.hashGenesisBlock = genesis.GetHash();
        assert(consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("0x12a765e31ffd4059bada1e25190f6e98c99d9714d334efa41a195a7e7e04bfe2"));
        assert(genesis.hashMerkleRoot == uint256S("0x97ddfbbae6be97fd6cdf3e7ca13232a3afff2353e29badfab7f73011edd4ced9"));

        // Note that of those with the service bits flag, most only support a subset of possible options
        vSeeds.emplace_back("seed-a.altcoin.loshan.co.uk", true);


        base58Prefixes[PUBKEY_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,48);
        base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,5);
        base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS2] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,50);
        base58Prefixes[SECRET_KEY] =     std::vector<unsigned char>(1,176);
        base58Prefixes[EXT_PUBLIC_KEY] = {0x04, 0x88, 0xB2, 0x1E};
        base58Prefixes[EXT_SECRET_KEY] = {0x04, 0x88, 0xAD, 0xE4};

        vFixedSeeds = std::vector<SeedSpec6>(pnSeed6_main, pnSeed6_main + ARRAYLEN(pnSeed6_main));

        fDefaultConsistencyChecks = false;
        fRequireStandard = true;
        fMineBlocksOnDemand = false;

        checkpointData = (CCheckpointData) {
            {
                {  1500, uint256S("0x841a2965955dd288cfa707a755d05a54e45f8bd476835ec9af4402a2b59a2967")}
            }
        };

        chainTxData = ChainTxData{
            // Data as of block 59c9b9d3fec105bdc716d84caa7579503d5b05b73618d0bf2d5fa639f780a011 (height 1353397).
            1516406833, // * UNIX timestamp of last known number of transactions
            19831879,  // * total number of transactions between genesis and that timestamp
                    //   (the tx=... number in the SetBestChain debug.log lines)
            0.06     // * estimated number of transactions per second after that timestamp
        };
    }
};
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I guess I qualify as *don't know the bitcoin/Litecoin Source program*, but still I can clearly see that you are asking three questions there. Are you sure that the three questions are close enough to one-another, that it's justified to post only one instead of three stackoverflow questions for it? Also your Title is very unspecific and I think this is because your question has no clear focus.

Comment: These are my doubts in the alt-coin development, These questions are not close enough, These are the topics that are not deeply discussed in cryptocurrency in anywhere. So I raised this as a single question to help others too in future developments..

Comment: Well, Stackoverflow is definitely not the right place to start a discussion. It is not a programmers forum but a question and answer site. Each topic should start with a clear question. For discussions, please visit the chat rooms or find a suitable developers forum

Comment: I do have 3 Questions raised which is still unanswered